# Non active record model validation i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a model that is not a child of ActiveRecord. I would like to internationalize the validation error messages.

```
class User
    validates_format_of :phone, :with => /someregex/ , message => :'Incorrect phone number'
end
```

If i just use `:message => I18n.t(:'errors.models.user.attributes.phone.invalid')` it always returns the string from en.yml irrespective of the locale of the user.

I would like to avoid using ActiveModel::EachValidator since it doesn't work with client side validations.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the following works as expected.

**en.yml**

```
 activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            phone: 
              invalid: "PhoneNumber is invalid"
```

**user.rb**

```
validates  :phonenumber, :format => { with: /someregex/ }
```

Comment: but, this will return the message 'Phone PhoneNumber is invalid' right? Is that what you expect?

Comment: When :phone doesn't match the regex the error message just says "PhoneNumber is invalid".